# Date autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply a filter on a column using vba autofilter. I want to select all dates which are in bracket of 60 to 100 days old can we do it using vba?

that is what i tried

```
Dim StartDate As Date 
Dim EndDate As Date
StartDate = Date - 100 
EndDate = Date - 60 
Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please include that in your question if you would like help.

Comment: Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
StartDate = Date - 100
EndDate = Date - 60
Worksheets("sheet1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)

Comment: Please include it in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typecasting the date to a long before applying it to the auto filter. Something like this should do the trick for you.  Adjust the range and field as appropraite for your needs.

```
Sub filterDates()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim r As Range

StartDate = Date - 100
EndDate = Date - 60
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

r.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(StartDate), _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<" & CLng(EndDate)

End Sub
```