# Autofilter for date range and include blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date column at column 16. I want to filter between July 1, 2022 and July 31, 2022 and include all the blanks, as well. My code lines below didn't seem to work for me. If you can help, I will be very thankful.

```
Sub function1()

startdate = #7/1/2022#    
enddate = #7/31/2022# 

Dim sh As Worksheet 
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 16, "=", xlOr, "<=" & enddate 
sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 16, ">=" & startdate, xlOr, "="

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532192/date-autofilter)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub date_filter()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourWorksheetName")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastCol As Long: lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array("="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "7/31/2022")
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Good Luck